# Configuring mysql database for psiturk experiment

Tags: mysql, database

I recently picked up a task at a lab I volunteer at and my PI said their experiment wasn't working because no workers were able to complete the task...

My hypothesis is that their sqlite implementation doesn't allow for proper recording of experimental data due to sqlite's ineffectiveness at concurrent operations (as stated in the psiturk documentation).
My question is, how can I properly set up a mysql database to work with their already made experiment?

I created a new database called "particpants" from the mysql interpreter. Then I started the mysql server successfully...

Next, I changed the `database_url` in the "config.txt" file from being equal to `sqlite://participants.db` (a local database file) to being equal to `mysql://aweeeezy@localhost:3306/participants`, but I can not connect to the database when I try to start the psiturk server.

I also tried `mysql://aweeeezy@localhost/particpants`...I can't figure out how to format this database_url string so that the experiment works with mysql, and I haven't found anything helpful when searching through mysql related posts and/or psiturk related posts.

Please help a databases noob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for the database_url field of config.txt using MySQL needs to be mysql://username:password@hostname/database.  psiTurk 2.0 depends on SQLAlchemy and some docs about that are here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/engines.html